# Highcharts - Custom X axis format

Tags: highcharts

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a custom ordering or format for the xAxis in highcharts. My dataset has a date time which would be used for the xAxis however my client has specified that it should show the 'Period' on the xAxis. A period is specified as a 30 minute slice - meaning there are 48 periods in a day.

The range of the data is from a period on the previous day to the current day with that period. For example 06/03/2017 Period 11 (10:00) to 07/03/2017 Period 11, the xAxis should look like so:

[image]

Currently I've attempted to do this by fiddling with the actual dateTime of each point, so that it is set to Y-m-d H:i:{Period} and then using the dateFormat to only show seconds on the xAxis. However this leaves a gap in data between 2017-03-06 23:59:{Period 48} and 2017-03-07 00:00:{Period 11}

Comment: So you've got your points based on timestamps, but you're missing the correct label on the X-axis? I wouldn't touch the model (the timestamp). I'd create a function f.x. `createLabelFromTimestamp(timestamp)`. Then extract the HMS and calculate the period based on them. If it is 0 then return date instead of period-number.

Comment: And how would i get this to show in the xAxis labels?

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: appologies I'm failing to get this sorted, in the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kyL093au/
how do I get the x axis to display the 'sp' value?

Comment: That doesn't seem like something you'd want to do... Could you show a bit of your data? How is it specified? I'm assuming your series data is like `[[<timestamp in milliseconds>, <value>], [<timestamp in millseconds>, <value>]]`, f.x `[[1800000, 5], [3600000, 10]]`...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your series-data is arranged as pairs of `[<timestamp in milliseconds>, <value>]` you can leave your data alone and simple do calculations and presentation of the label.

To show the labels as we want we use `xAxis.labels.formatter` (and possibly `tickInterval` to space them as we want). For example:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return createLabelFromTimestamp(this.value);
        }
    },
    tickInterval: 1800000
}
```

The calculation of the period number (as described in question) can be done for example like this:

```
function createLabelFromTimestamp(timestamp) {
    var hms = timestamp % (1800000 * 48);
    var period = hms / 1800000;

    // if 0-th period, show date instead
    if(period == 0) {
        var date = new Date(timestamp);
        return date.toDateString();
    }
    // otherwise show period number
    else {
        return period;
    }
}
```

We simply modulo away the day and divide to find what 30-minute segment we are in.

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kyL093au/1/) of it in action.